# Extracting Date and Time info from a string.

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, datetime, database

I have a database full of data, including a date and time string, e.g. `Tue, 21 Sep 2010 14:16:17 +0000`

What I would like to be able to do is extract various documents (records) from the database based on the time contained within the date string, `Tue, 21 Sep 2010 14:16:17 +0000`.

From the above date string, how would I use python and regex to extract documents that have the time `15:00:00`? I'm using MongoDB by the way, in conjunction with Python.

Comment: Wait...aren't you using a sql (or equivilant) statement to pull the data? I think that it would have better capabilities than rex.  I think you now have two problems. ;o)

Comment: it's literally stored as date = "Tue, 21 Sep 2010 14:16:17 +0000", I want to extract all records with the time 15:00, not just ones on Tuesday or in September. You understand?

Comment: Oh, yes, I understand you want it to pull across all dates with the times of 1500 but, for instance, in sql you'd just extract the hours from the date/time field and put it in your WHERE clause. If it were a text field, in sql, you'd just convert it to a date/time and then grab the time out of it.

Comment: maybe it's to be a better idea to save date and times in different places so that you can query against them easily, it's a first of golden rules in relational database design although your db is not relational, it's better to you to have your domains data structures and objects :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$where](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D):

```
db.collection.find({$where: "var d = new Date(this.dateProperty); return d.getUTCHours() == 15 && d.getUTCMinutes() == 0 && d.getUTCSeconds() == 0"})
```

Or regular expression:

```
db.collection.find({dateProperty: /.*15:00.*/})
```

The second can be a bit faster than first but both will be relatively slow. To speedup things you would store dates in built-in `date` format. Also if you need to query on datetime components consider adding indexable date representation such as `{y:2010,m:9,d:21,h:14,i:16,s:17}` (properties depend on your query needs, if you only need to query by hour you would have `{h:14}`). Then you can have index per each component.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know MongoDB, but shouldn't something like this work?

```
SELECT * FROM Database WHERE Date LIKE '%15:00:00%'
```

If you have a date string, the only place it contains colons will be the time part of the date, so that should be good enough without a regex. It would be better, of course, if you had an actual timestamp instead of a string in your date field.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other poster. Though this doesn't solve your immediate problem, if you have any control over the database, you should seriously consider creating a time/column, with either a DATE or TIMESTAMP datatype. That would make your system much more robust, & completely avoid the problem of trying to parse dates from string (an inherently fragile technique).

Answer (score 1):

To keep things easy, use:

```python
import datetime, dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse("Tue, 21 Sep 2010 14:16:17 +0000").strftime('%X')
# '14:16:17'
```